# Android Compose LazyColumn inside another LazyColumn\scrollable Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement scrollable screen with two non-scrollable lists inside it using Compose. My first attempt was to use Column(modifier = verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) and LazyColumns inside. Obviously it does not work, so I tried to find a solution on SO. All answers I have found can be reduced to one: flatten everything to the items of one LazyColumn.
However it does not answer what to do if some group of items (1) must be decorated by border, and another (2) must have separators between items.

[image]

The only way to implement this I see is to manually add all items of these lists to one large scrollable Column, adding padding to modifiers and separators as views, but it is ugly.

Is there any way to do it better?

Comment: You can flatten everything and appoint a view type to each of the groups. Then you can fully customise per view type

Comment: @ElizaCamber Sorry, I didn't get your comment. right now I have (1) as separate compose fun a(), adding it to the outer LazyColumn with item{ a() }, and inside a() I'm creating another LazyColumn to populate it's items. How can I flatten it?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: No, prohibited by NDA :(

Comment: you can use placeholders and not your actual composable names. With the info provided I don't think you'll get much help from anyone